# value not defined for #ifdef using gcc and makefile

Tags: c, makefile, conditional-compilation

So I am trying to learn how makefiles work to compile programs in c, But I can’t define something using gcc and main.o as “*OBJS*” I have this simple main function and makefile in which I try to define *test*

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    #ifdef test
        printf("ok\n");
    #else 
        printf("not ok\n"); 
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

makefile

```
MODULES = ../
OBJS = main.o
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
PROGRAM = defineprog

$(PROGRAM): clean $(OBJS)
    gcc -D test $(OBJS) -o $(PROGRAM)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAM) $(OBJS)

run: $(PROGRAM)
    ./$(PROGRAM)
```

Every time I compile my program and then execute it I always get the output "not ok" which means that test is not defined, does anyone know how to make this work using the main.o as “*OBJS*”. 
Thanks

Comment: `$(PROGRAM): clean $(OBJS)` makes no sense. You're telling make that your program depends on both creating all object files (`$(OBJS)`) and deleting all object files (`clean`).

Comment: `-D test` is a preprocessor option. It doesn't do anything when you call gcc on object files. (This has nothing to do with make.)

Answer (score 1):

You need the define for the command that does the *compilation* not linking.

In your setup that command is implicit (found in Make's database as a rule for creating `*.o` files out of `*.c` files) but it does use the `CFLAGS` Make variable, so what you can do is add `-Dtest` to your `CFLAGS` Make variable:

```
OBJS = main.o
CFLAGS = -Dtest -g -Wall
PROGRAM = defineprog

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS)
    gcc -D test $(OBJS) -o $(PROGRAM)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAM) $(OBJS)

run: $(PROGRAM)
  ./$(PROGRAM)
```